# HTML file will not use other files or links

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

When i use HTML if i try to use a link or file it has a "file could not be found error" it wouldn't work with images, links, Css files, or relitive files here is my code:

```
<head>
    <title>VIDCOM</title>
    <link href=“styles/main.css” rel=“stylesheet” type=“text/css” />    
</head>

<body>
    <h1>VIDCOM</h1>
    Test
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>   
        <li><a href=“Gaming.html”>Gaming</a></li>
    </ul>

</body>
```

Ps: I use Text edit

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<li><a href="Gaming.html">Gaming</a></li>
```

instead of

```
<li><a href=“Gaming.html”>Gaming</a></li>
```

Comment: ^ Beat me to it.

Comment: I have two questions how do i do the other type of quotation marks? also how do i fix the link to my css file

Comment: See answer of @michael-coker. You are using wrong quotation marks in the head of the html file as well. This is the reason the css file is also not found.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [disable fancy/smart quotes in textedit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120486/quotes-problem-in-mavericks-or-textedit). Those are special characters in HTML and will not work like regular quotes. Here's your updated HTML.

```
<head>
    <title>VIDCOM</title>
    <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
</head>

<body>
    <h1>VIDCOM</h1>
    Test
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>   
        <li><a href="Gaming.html">Gaming</a></li>
    </ul>

</body>
```